# Find row elements of a matrix using an index matrix with NaN values

Tags: matlab

I have the following matrix `c = [1 2 NaN;2 NaN 1;4 1 NaN;3 NaN NaN]` and another matrix `A = [ 16     2     3    13; 5    11    10     8; 9     7     6    12; 4    14    15     1 ]`. We initialize matrix `B=nan(size(A))`. I want to use each row of `c` as an index of each row of `A` and store the results in the corresponding elements of `B`. For example, for c(1,:) = [1 2 NaN], and `B(1,:) = [16 2 NaN NaN ]`, c(4,:) = [3 NaN NaN] and B(4,:) = [NaN NaN 15 NaN];

A possible solution I think is:

```
B= nan(size(A));
for i=1:size(A,1)
    B(i,c(i,~isnan(c(i,:)))) = A(i,c(i,~isnan(c(i,:)))) ;
end
```

I am trying it to do it with out for loops but with no success so far because in each row of `c` may have different number of `NaN` values.

Can we do this without `for loops`?

Thank you!

Comment: I vaguely wonder whether you should be making c and B sparse matrices, as opposed to using all of these NaNs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 c(isnan(c))=0;  %better not to use NaNs in the first place?

 [I,~,J]=find(c);

 idx=sub2ind(size(A),I,J);

 B = NaN(size(A));

 B(idx)=A(idx);
```

Comment: If you add the line `B = NaN(size(A));` you get exactly to the OPs `B`. +1

Comment: The OP said he already had done that, but okay...more self-contained.

Comment: Sorry didn't see that